# Throttle routes for premium-users

Tags: php, laravel

I want to throttle pages for premium-users.

web.php:

```php
$throttlePost = '';
$throttleView = '';
if(Auth::user()->isPremium()) {
    $throttlePost = '99999999999';
    $throttleView = '99999999999';
} else {
    $throttlePost = '2';
    $throttleView = '2';
}

Route::middleware('throttle:' . $throttlePost . ',60')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/create', 'PostController@create');
    Route::post('/like', 'PostController@like')->middleware('auth');
});
```

But it returns `Call to a member function isPremium() on null`

My user model looks like this:

```php
public function isPremium() {
   if($this->premium >= 1 && $this->premium <= 3) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Is there no option to use the Auth::user() class in the web.php? Or is there even a better way to achieve this?

```php
dd(Auth::user())
```

also returns null

Doing

```php
use Auth;
```

gives me an error: `The use statement with non-compound name 'Auth' has no effect`

Comment: `auth()->user()` ?

Comment: returns the same error ```Call to a member function isPremium() on null ```

Comment: Try adding a \ before `Auth`

Comment: returns the same error..

Comment: You don't need to do "use Auth" in Route! , try with a controller and check if it works, i'm guessing the Api Auth middleware didn't get fired yet at that point (try to dd auth::user() in controller) if that works it means you need to use a middleware to make this work

Comment: Did you call auth()->attempt($credentails)? Did you use standard Auth guard? If your user didn't go through attemp/validate - auth()->user() return null. That is why your method doesn't exists.

Comment: It works when I do if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isPremium()) but then it takes the else statement instead of the if statement, although I am currently logged in as Premium.

Comment: Your if statement mean - if your Auth::check() return null - go to else statement. So I suggest call Auth::check() before your your try to call isPremium or modify else staement to esleif (Auth::check() && !Auth::user()->isPremium()